# Create extern char array in C

Tags: c, char, extern

How to create an external character array in C?

I have tried various ways to define `char cmdval[128]` but it always says `undefined reference to 'cmdval'`

I want to put a string in cmdval in `first.c` file and use it in other `second.c` file. I tried adding a `global.h` file with `extern char cmdval[128]` but no luck.

UPDATE:

**global.h**

```
extern char cmdval[128];
```

**first.c**

```
#include "global.h"

char cmdval[128];

function(){
   strcpy(cmdval, "a string");
}
```

**second.c**

```
#include "global.h"

function(){
   printf("%s \n",cmdval); //error
}
```

FAIL :( "undefined reference to `cmdval'"

EDIT:
I am working in linux (editing a mini OS xv6 then compiling and running it in qemu), I don't know if it is a barrier

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling both files and linking them together? Are you sure both files are `.c` or `.cpp`, not a mix of the two? Do you actually `#include "global.h"` in `second.c`?

Comment: I rechecked and sure that both are `.c`, both `#include "global.h", but not sure about linking both.

Comment: So, exactly how do you compile and link this code?

Comment: @Alex - `gcc first.c second.c -o main` but his example is incomplete, have a look at the example in my answer

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to declare it in the .h file

```
extern char cmdval[128];
```

And then define the value in first.c;

```
char cmdval[128];
```

Then anything that includes your .h file, provided it is linked with first.o will have access to it.

To elaborate, "extern" is saying, there is an external variable that this will reference... if you dont then declare cmdval somewhere, cmdval will never exist, and the extern reference will never reference anything.

Example:

global.h:

```
extern char cmdval[128];
```

first.c:

```
#include "global.h"
char cmdval[128];

int main() {
  strcpy(cmdval, "testing");
  test();
}
```

second.c:

```
#include "global.h"

void test() {
  printf("%s\n", cmdval);
}
```

You can compile this using:

```
gcc first.c second.c -o main
```

Or make the .o files first and link them

```
gcc -c first.c -o first.o
gcc -c second.c -o second.o
gcc first.o second.o -o main
```

Comment: 'provided it is linked with first.o' what does that mean?

Comment: Also do i need to define char cmdval in second.c?

Comment: They are part of the same binary, eg: `gcc first.c second.c -o main`, and no, you only declare cmdval once, but you still need the extern in global.h

Comment: Take the `128` out of the extern declaration. `extern char cmdval[]` is enough. If you leave a value in the declaration and the definition is changed, the declaration's value will be ignored.

Comment: I am working in linux (editing a mini OS xv6 then compiling and running it in qemu), I don't know if it is a barrier

Comment: I just compiled my example using `gcc first.c second.c -o main` and then ran it as `./main` which produced `testing`

Comment: are these two .c files part of the same project/binary?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4057/discussion-between-geoffrey-and-lifeh2o)

Comment: Using the 128 in the `.h` file declaration is usually the *right* thing to do; if it conflicts the definition in the `.c` file then you will get a compile-time error (provided you include the `.h` file in the `.c` file, which is exactly why you should do that).  Including the size in the declaration means that it will have a complete type in all translation units.

Comment: @caf - good good point, didnt even think of that, thanks, re-updating the example.

Comment: Why do I get an error when I use `extern char* cmdval;` instead (in the `.h` file)?

Comment: @ElliotGorokhovsky you have not provided enough information. Please ask your question as a new question with details, this is not the place to ask about a separate issue.

Comment: No worries, I figured it out. It was a simple error with my include guards.

Answer (score 4):

`Extern` doesn't mean find it somewhere, it changes the variable `linkage` to `external`, which means no matter how many time you declare a variable, it references to the same thing.

e.g. These references the same thing in c(not c++), a global variable's linkage by default is `external`.

```
external char cmdval[128];
char cmdval[];
char cmdval[128];
```

The problem is that you shoud first compile them into .o, then link those .o together.

```
gcc -c first.c second.c
gcc -o first.o second.o
```

or

```
gcc first.c second.c
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a compilation unit in which you *define* the `cmdval` variable. The `extern` keyword *only declares* that the variable exists, it does not define it.

Put the following line in `first.c`, `second.c` or in an other C file of your choice:

```
char cmdval[128];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `second.c`

```
#include "global.h"
```

define `extern char cmdval[128]` in `global.h` as well.