# Split up code in multiple source files, now I'm getting an array error

Tags: c++, c++11

I originally had all this code in one source file because I misread the assignment instructions. Then I saw it said please do NOT have all this code in one source file and I thought that made much more sense.

It compiled just fine when I had everything in my main.cpp, but now it's giving me:

> error: invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript"

In my main I have the array declared like:

```
#include "CaesarEncryptDecrypt.h"

using namespace std;
string pFile, cFile;
char textFile{1000};

int main()
{
//rest of main code...
```

and in my header I have it declared like:

```
// Globals
extern string pFile, cFile;
extern char textFile;
```

but then it gets to my two source code files and it shows errors here:

```
void encrypt (int shift, ifstream & plainTextFile, ofstream & cipherFile){
    char letter;
    int i = 0;
    while(!plainTextFile.eof()){
            plainTextFile.get(textFile[i]);
            /* 'error: invalid types 'char[int]' <--This error shows up at 
               every instance of me trying to use textFile 
               array. */

            i++;
    }
```

I'm sure I've missed something obvious here.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have a variable of type `char` that is initialized with a value of 1000

`char textFile{1000};`

when it appears you want a `char` array of length 1000.  To do this you would need to change your definition to

`char textFile[1000];`

to create a `char` array (note the square braces).  Then in your header you need to declare `textFile` as an `extern` array:

`extern char textFile[1000];`

Comment: I did that and it fixed my other errors, but now I'm getting 'error: conflicting declaration 'char textFile [1000]'

Comment: I fixed my previous post.  The header declaration needs to match the definition.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670816/create-extern-char-array-in-c) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it. I can't believe I didn't notice the brackets lol, feel like an idiot.